# Looking for a regex to check input for short 4 character string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a way to check an input string to see if it follows a specific pattern `1-x digit number` followed by `a specific letter` followed by more numbers. I was going this way with it

`/^([0-9]{1,10}+(?:\r)+[0-9]{1,2})+$/`

however I got this error when inputting what was supposed to be a valid input

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^([0-9]{1,10}+(?:\r)+[0-9]{1,2})+$/: Nothing to repeat

I am unable to determine what exactly is wrong with my syntax since I use a similar method for validating emails

Comment: [Regular Expressions 101: Online regex tester and debugger: JavaScript, Python, PHP, and PCRE](https://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you that tool was very helpful I was able to piece together a working regex.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `+` after `{1,10}`. `+` needs to precede by a valid token to match a repeat of it, but here it preceded by `{1,10}` which shows the [limiting Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) :

```
/^([0-9]{1,10}+(?:\r)+[0-9]{1,2})+$/
              ^
```